# Trying to use the "Iterate Datasets" tool with .dwg files

Tags: arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, cad, iterator, dwg

I'm trying to expand on a model created by a co-worker that uses the Point and Polyline CAD feature classes within a .dwg to perform a number of geoprocessing tasks.  My goal is to be able to have the location of the .dwg be a parameter for the model and run the model for all of the .dwg files in the folder.  I thought that the "Iterate Datasets" tool would do exactly what I'm trying to do but for some reason the model hits the "Iterate Datasets" tool and then quickly finishes successfully without anything in the rest of the model running.  It acts like it looks in the folder, finds nothing to run, and therefore finishes successfully.  Does this tool not work with .dwg datasets?

The CAD data goes into two separate sub-models after it is iterated.  I rearranged things a little hoping to give a better perspective in the full image.

The only parameter going into the iterator is the folder for the location of the .dwg files.

@Hornbydd, also, this is a bit different now as I'm trying to parse the filename to better name the output folders/gdb/outputs to suit my needs.  Sill having the same problem though.

[image: Full Model]

[image: Success]

Comment: Just checked and it worked for me, I had the iterator creating folders based upon the dwg name. Can you edit your question to show how you set the iterator up? What are the parameter values going into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this... Quite simple actually....  It involved rearranging my mess of preconditions as seen in the picture.  I think the model was trying to run the create folder section prior to the actual iteration.